# Using Static variables in angular router link path

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, typescript3.0

In my angular app, I have a Path file where all the path variables are static like below.

```
export class PATHS {
    static LOGIN = "login";
    static HOME = "home";
}
```

In my Layout component I was using them in router link like below

```
 <li class="nav-item" title="Home">
   <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/' + PATHS.HOME]"> Home </a>
 </li>
```

Getting a build error **Property 'HOME' is a static member of type 'PATHS'.**

**This was working in Angular 6 after upgrading to Angular 8 and typescript 3.5**

I can fix this by hardcoding the path instead of using it from static variable but this I find a better approach. Any fix?

Comment: maybe you should use this 
 <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/' ,PATHS.HOME]"> Home </a>

Comment: Hi Piyush, tried this earlier it was not working

Answer (score 0):

Please try following.

If your `PATHS` class is in another directory then import it in your component file like below.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PATHS } from 'your path here';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent  {
  public Path = PATHS;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<li class="nav-item" title="Home">
   <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/' + Path.HOME]"> Home </a>
</li>
```